# Powershell - Formatting column as date

Tags: powershell, csv

I am importing a CSV which has 5 "columns".  One of them is a date and time.  The 3rd party software that is reading this column, then does not sort the date well.

IE: (4/8/2022 1:24:08 PM) will sort above (4/13/2022 8:51:52 AM)

Even though 4/13 is after 4/8 it will not sort it properly.  I would like to add a leading zero in front of the month and date with powershell.  I did do some searching but nothing seems to make sense to me, I am not a HUGE programmer.

Thanks for any help!

This is what I am currently doing.  I am using unique to remove duplicate rows (this is needed for what I am doing).

```
$FinalSessions = Import-Csv -Path "C:\Windows\AdminArsenal\UserSessions.csv"  | Sort-Object * -Unique
$FinalSessions | Export-Csv -Path "C:\Windows\AdminArsenal\UserSessions.csv"  -NoTypeInformation
$FinalSessions
```

Comment: Please share an example of your CSV and your expected output as plain text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Get-Date to actually get a datetime object and then reformat it.
It would look something like this:

```
$FinalSessions = Import-Csv -Path "C:\Windows\AdminArsenal\UserSessions.csv"| Sort-Object * -Unique
$FinalSessions | % { $_.DateColumn = Get-Date $_.DateColumn -Format "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt" }
$FinalSessions | Export-Csv -Path 
"C:\Windows\AdminArsenal\UserSessions.csv"  -NoTypeInformation
$FinalSessions
```

Just replace "DateColumn" with the name of your column

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the column that contains the date-time string is named `Date` (adjust as needed):

```
Import-Csv -Path C:\Windows\AdminArsenal\UserSessions.csv | 
  ForEach-Object { $_.Date = ([datetime] $_.Date).ToString('s') } | 
    Sort-Object * -Unique -OutVariable finalSessions |
      Export-Csv -Path C:\Windows\AdminArsenal\UserSessions.csv -NoTypeInformation

$finalSessions
```

Note that the [`s` format specifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings#the-sortable-s-format-specifier) (in ISO 8601 format) is used to reformat the date-time strings, as that results in a string whose lexical sorting reliably indicates chronological order, *across year boundaries*; e.g. `2022-05-05T17:52:47`